# Datetime Module and Timedelta

Tags: python-3.x

I need to add onehour to the currenttime and subtract it with the minutes, e

For example:current time = 7:31,addedhour = 7:31 + 1 hour = 8:31,required time = 8:31 - 31 = 8:00

Any help or a workaround will be greatly appreciated.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import time
addedtime = (datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=1)).strftime('%H:%M')
    requiredtime = addedtime - timedelta(now.minutes).strftime('%H:%M')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting `addedtime` to a *string* rather than a `datetime`, then getting into trouble because you're trying to subtract a `timedelta` *from* that string:

```
>>> addedtime = (datetime.now() + timedelta(hours=1)).strftime('%H:%M')
>>> addedtime
'23:30'
>>> addedtime - timedelta(minutes=4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

Instead, *keep* them as timepoints for as long as you need to *manipulate* them as timepoints, converting them to a string when you need the final result:

```
>>> time1 = datetime.now()
>>> time1
datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 17, 22, 23, 55, 860195)

>>> time2 = time1 + timedelta(hours=1)
>>> time2
datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 17, 23, 23, 55, 860195)

>>> time3 = time2 - timedelta(minutes=time2.minute)
>>> time3
datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 17, 23, 0, 55, 860195)

>>> time3.strftime("%H:%M")
'23:00'
```

---

Of course, you can also do it as a single operation since you can both add one hour and subtract some minutes with a single `timedelta`:

```
>>> final = (time1 + timedelta(hours=1, minutes=-time1.minute)).strftime("%H:%M")
>>> final
'23:00'
```

Comment: Thanks a lott, @paxdiablo, new to coding so not familiar how certain modules work.

Comment: can you help me with my second problem?

Comment: @Raghul, the normal use for SO is one question, one answer. If you have a subsequent question, it's best to actually ask a new question (referring back to this one if necessary, bit it's not in this case since it's a totally different issue).

Comment: Okay I'll post a new a question. Thank you )

Answer (score 0):

Why not explore one of Python's many amazing datetime libraries ...

**pip install parsedatetime**

```
import parsedatetime as pdt
from datetime import datetime

if __name__ == '__main__':        
    cal = pdt.Calendar()
    dt, result = cal.parse("10 minutes before an hour from now")
    print(datetime(*dt[:6]))
```